# Unable to return json response in Yii2 api

Tags: json, api, rest, response, yii2-advanced-app

I am trying to return a `JSON` response.

```
$rec = Yii::$app->hescoMDC->createCommand(/** @lang text */ "SELECT * FROM a_data_catalogue d WHERE d.`METER_ASSET_NO` = '$new_msn' AND d.`DISCARD_TIME` IS NULL")->queryOne();
             
 if($rec['CONS_NO'])
                {

                    
                    Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
                    return Json::encode([
                        'status' => 'Not OK',
                        'description' => 'New msn is already attached with a customer ' . $rec['CONS_NO'].' MCO can`t be done'
                    ]);
                       
                }
```

I am using `postman` to check the response but I am getting an **empty** window.

Comment: You should show more of your code to give more context. Beside that, are you sure something is getting returned? Did you step through this with a debugger or similar? Lastly you may be double encoding the json by setting the response format then explicitly encoding again.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, when you are using:

```
  Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
```

you don't need use `Json::encode()` in return. Just return array